# How to solve this custom post type goes to 404 page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, 404-error

I have a custom post type called `dramas`

```
/******* DRAMAS BEGIN *****************************************/
register_post_type('dramas', array(
    'label' => 'Dramas',
    'show_ui' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'description'),
    'labels' => array (
        'name' => 'Dramas',
        'singular_name' => 'Drama',
        'menu_name' => 'Dramas'
    ),
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'drama' ),
) );
```

I have set up a custom `taxonomy` for the post

```
/* register taxonomy only for DRAMAS*/
register_taxonomy(
    'drama_taxonomy',
    'dramas',
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => 'Category',
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true
    )
);
```

I am able to get these post anywhere using following code

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'dramas', 'posts_per_page' => 4 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();                           
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'drama_realityshow_home_page_thumb', true);  
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'drama_taxonomy' ); 
?>
<div class="prime-item">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" class="standard-height">
    <img src="<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>" width="300" height="168" class="hoverZoomLink">
  </a>
  <div class="new-cat"><?php 
    foreach($terms as $term) {
      echo $term->name;
    } ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

By using the above code I am getting `dramas` custom post type's

1. Thumbnail source
2. Taxonomy term
3. Permalink

When I hover over the  I see the permalink / url `www.mysite.com/drama/post-name` at the browser bottom as I expected.
But when I click on the link [ 'a' tag in the `<div class="prime-item">`] I am getting 404 page.

I have `single-dramas.php` in the theme folder. Even if I don not have that it should fall to `single.php` but it's not.

The browser address bar shows `www.mysite.com/drama/post-name` but displaying 404.

Also permalink edit option is NOT found at the right bottom of the editor title as always it's appeared.

[image: PERMALINK EDITOR]

why is this?
How can I get to single page / the permalink works for the post type `dramas`? NOT to go to 404.

Comment: You will need to save permalink settings again.

Comment: I've tried that by visiting to `Admin Panel -> Setting -> Permalinks` and clicked `save` but NO luck.. still same 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You custom post type is **NO**T public.

Add following lines to your **register_post_type** `array`

```
'public' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
```

Answer (score 1):

Your custom post type is not publicly visible so you need to update your argument

You can refer given link for that https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

And if your custom post type publicly visible and still problem exist please Flush your permalink and try it.
It will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks .. as I mentioned in comment I already flushed my permalinks.. I upvoted you.. thanks for the time...